# gsub() on header in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file that looks like

```
    X90045GridMs.TotPFPrc X90045Inv.TmpLimStt X90042InvCtl.Stt X90042Mode
1        NA                        NA                   NA             NA
2        0.00                       1                    3              7
3        0.44                       1                    2              1
4        0.80                       1                    2              1
5        0.88                       1                    2              1
6        0.93                       1                    2              1
7        0.95                       1                    2              1
8        0.98                       1                    2              1
9        0.99                       1                    2              1
```

where the headers are made up of a serial no. and a parameter name. I would like to change the headers from X90045 and X90042 to Inv 1 and Inv 2 using gsub. Is there such a method to use gsub on the header? The end result should look something like this:

```
    Inv1GridMs.TotPFPrc      Inv1Inv.TmpLimStt      Inv2InvCtl.Stt    Inv2Mode
1        NA                         NA                   NA            NA
2        0.00                       1                    3              7
3        0.44                       1                    2              1
4        0.80                       1                    2              1
5        0.88                       1                    2              1
6        0.93                       1                    2              1
7        0.95                       1                    2              1
8        0.98                       1                    2              1
9        0.99                       1                    2              1
```

Comment: The header can be grabbed/inspected with `names(dat)` and replaced with `names(dat) <- mynewnames`. If you're asking for the regular expression to use with `gsub`... what have you tried?

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I needed! I tried reading the file with header=FALSE and then using gsub, though that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your data in a data.frame object? If so you can access and modify the header using names().

```
names(yourdata) <- gsub("X90045", "Inv1", names(yourdata))
```

and likewise for your other field.